# Invoke-WebRequest alterative in PowerShell v5

Tags: windows-server-2016, powershell-5.0

In previous versions of PowerShell, I used `Invoke-WebRequest` to download files from HTTP. While using Server 2016 Nano with PowerShell 5.1, I found out that this command has been removed!

How am I supposed to download files from the internet in a virtually PowerShell only OS? Have I missed something? Why did Microsoft remove this?

I understand that I can use .NET commands, but that's a lot more effort than one command.

$PSVersionTable:

```
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSEdition                      Core
    PSVersion                      5.1.14284.1000
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
    BuildVersion                   10.0.14284.1000
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34011
```

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/788949/download-a-file-with-powershell-on-nano-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` works fine in PowerShell 5.1.14393.0 on Windows 10 Pro.

PowerShell on a Nano Server is not the same as a Desktop/Full Server version, it's the PowerShell Core version, not the Desktop version.  So certain commands/abilities will be missing when using a Nano Server.

From Microsoft's TechNet - ["PowerShell on Nano Server"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/nano-server/powershell-on-nano-server):

> Starting with version 5.1, PowerShell is available in different
>   editions which denote varying feature sets and platform compatibility.
>
> - Desktop Edition: Built on .NET Framework and provides compatibility with scripts and modules targeting versions of PowerShell running on
>     full footprint editions of Windows such as Server Core and Windows
>     Desktop.
> - Core Edition: Built on .NET Core and provides compatibility with scripts and modules targeting versions of PowerShell running on
>     reduced footprint editions of Windows such as Nano Server and Windows
>     IoT.

And under "Windows PowerShell features not available in Nano Server" in the same article:

> - Web-related cmdlets { Invoke-WebRequest, Invoke-RestMethod, New-WebServiceProxy, Send-MailMessage, ConvertTo-Html }

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a short way to do this I presume? I feel it would be a important feature in nano server.